# out-file -filepath $target -append work in ISE but fails otherwise

Tags: file, powershell, out, powershell-ise

I have created a script to build a SQL query file from a CSV file. When I run it in ISE it works fine and builds the files exactly as I would expect. But If I try to launch the script from either powershell or from a cmd session I get the error:

```
Out-File : The process cannot access the file
'C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Working\terrorist525.sql' because it is
being used by another process.
```

The script is as follows:

```
$start | out-file -filepath $target1 -append
$infile = $source1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($infile)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $file1;

$counter = 1
try {
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
    {
        $myarray=$line -split "\t" | foreach {$_.Trim()}
        if ($myarray[0] -Match "\d{1,4}\.\d{1,3}" -and $myarray[1] -ne {$null}){
$myarray[1] = $myarray[1] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[2] = $myarray[2] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[3] = $myarray[3] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[4] = $myarray[4] -replace "'","''"
$myarray[5] = $myarray[5] -replace "'","''"
"Insert into #terrorist Select convert(varchar(60),replace('OSFI Name: "+$myarray[1],$myarray[2],$myarray[3],$myarray[4],$myarray[5]+,"','''''','''')), no_,branch,name,surname,midname,usual,bname2 " | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append -force
If ($myarray[1] -eq "") {$myarray[1]=”~”}
If ($myarray[2] -eq "") {$myarray[2]=”~”}
If ($myarray[3] -eq "") {$myarray[3]=”~”}
If ($myarray[4] -eq "") {$myarray[4]=”~”}
If ($myarray[5] -eq "") {$myarray[5]=”~”}
"from cust where cust.surname in ('"+$myarray[2]+,"','"+$myarray[1]+,"','"+$myarray[3]+,"','"+$myarray[4]+,"','"+$myarray[5]+,"') and ( name in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
midname in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
usual in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') or 
bname2 in ('"+$myarray[1]+,"', '"+$myarray[2]+,"', '"+$myarray[3]+,"', '"+$myarray[4]+,"', '"+$myarray[5]+,"') ) 
go" | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append -force

        }   

            #$writer.WriteLine($original);

            #Write-Output  $original;
            #Write-Output  $newlin
    }
}
finally {
    $reader.Close()
    $writer.Close()
}

$end1 | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append
(GC $target1).replace("?","") | Set-Content $target1
```

It seems as if out-file is not letting go of the file when running `$start | add-content -path $target1`
Everything I have read says that this should not be the case.

Comment: `Out-File` doesn't lock files.  `*-Content` cmdlets do.

Comment: That is what I have read but my script still locks the file when run anywhere but from ISE

Comment: Close and re-open ISE, then test again. The only difference between a normal console and ISE should be pre-existing things you define.

Comment: If the first line in the sample you posted is the one that has the error, what happens to `$target1` file before that line. Seems like we are missing context of the code that has the actually error. Is there any `Out-File` to that line before the first line?

Comment: @JacobColvin While I agree with having them close the ISE and then try again, it is not true that the only difference between the console and the ISE is session persistence. At the very least the ISE runs (by default) in STA, while the console runs in MTA. The differences are subtle and few, but they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start | Out-File -filepath $target1 -append

$infile = $source1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($infile)
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $file1;
$writer.Close()
$counter = 1
try {
```

By adding in the $writer.close() in this specific spot it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not answer the question of why your file is getting locked, I do keep a function on hand that uses SysInternal's Handle.exe to remove locks from files.

```
Function Close-LockedFile{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Object[]]$InputFile
)
Begin{
    $HandleApp = 'C:\localbin\Handle.exe'
    If(!(Test-Path $HandleApp)){Write-Host "Handle.exe not found at $HandleApp`nPlease download it from www.sysinternals.com and save it in the afore mentioned location.";break}
}
Process{
    $HandleOut = Invoke-Expression ($HandleApp+' '+$InputFile.Fullname)
    $Locks = $HandleOut |?{$_ -match "(.+?)\s+pid: (\d+?)\s+type: File\s+(\w+?): (.+)\s*$"}|%{
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'AppName' = $Matches[1]
            'PID' = $Matches[2]
            'FileHandle' = $Matches[3]
            'FilePath' = $Matches[4]
        }
    }
    ForEach($Lock in $Locks){
        Invoke-Expression ($HandleApp + " -p " + $Lock.PID + " -c " + $Lock.FileHandle + " -y") | Out-Null
    }
    $InputFile
}
}
```